# Use the floating point instructions to get results in decimal

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi I'm coding a small program in MIPS that divide 2 between 9 and show the result.This is the code

```
li $t1, 2
li $t2, 9
li $v0, 2
div $t0,$t2,$t1
move $a0,$t0
syscall
```

(this is not the full code, just the section handling division)

So, 2 / 9 is 0.2222222222222222

But when I run it I only get 0.0

How I show the true result (0.2222222222222222)?

I've been said that I'm using integer instead of floating point, that I must use the floating point instructions to get results in decimal. That I should look up the div.x instruction, but div.x is not a recognized operator.

So, I'm pretty much in blank. I don't understand what to do.

Could someone post the code to show the floating point result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there something wrong with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513610/show-division-result-in-mips

Comment: You should consider tagging this as homework, since I can't think of any other reason to be working with MIPS.

Comment: @Ashir - If you need to explain your question better, please edit your previous question instead of opening a new one.  If you are looking for a better answer, give it some time.  Re-posting questions is not the right way to get them answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show division result in MIPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513610/show-division-result-in-mips)

Comment: I've merged your 3 questions into just this one. Please don't repost the same question over and over again (at least 2 of them were nearly identical.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, after a long try and mistake the right way to print the true result is:

Set 2 floating points registers using pseudo li.s (Thanks to Paul R for point me in the right direction)

```
li.s $f1, 2.0
li.s $f2, 9.0
```

Obviously, prepare to print a float

```
li $v0, 2
```

At division instead of `div $t0,$t2,$t1` I should use

```
div.s $f12,$f1,$f2
```

and instead of `move $a0,$t0` I should just

```
syscall
```

There is no need to move, div.s prints outs the result at once so there is no real need to move the contents of $f12 into $a0 for print its content.

It's a real shame that mars doesn't implment the pseudo li.s. I had to try this on PCSPIM...

The final code is

```
.globl main
.text
main:
li.s $f1, 2.0
li.s $f2, 9.0
li $v0, 2
div.s $f12,$f1,$f2
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

When you run it you'll get 0.22222222, the true result of dividing 2 between 9.

Comment: Hum, sorry men, maybe I don't read that on the chat. If I had read that I would have save time. I come to realized this the next night after we chat... Again, my apologies, it wasn't my intention to not giving you credits for your help, hope you'll understand that after 36 hours stright coding in assembly anyone tired can make such mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It's an *integer* division instruction, so `2 / 9 = 0` is the correct result. Try e.g. `27 / 9` and you should get a result of 3.

Comment: I don't get it, 2 / 9 it's 0.2222222222222222... How I show that result?

Comment: It's an **integer** division instruction. 2 / 9 = 0 remainder 2, so you get 0 for the result and a remainder of 2.

Comment: I still don't get it, how I divide 2 / 9 in MIPS so my on screen result is what I could get on a pocket calculator (0.2222222222222222)???

Comment: Let me see if I catch you... I'm using $t to store values to divide and result, and $a0 to print the result. Are you saying I should use $f0??? If so, what is the right sintax?

Comment: You need `div.s` for floating point division, and of course you'll ned to use the floating point register set. See e.g. http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html

Comment: I though that already but I can't use it because beside divide them I also add them, substract them and multiply them. So, I set `li $f1, 2` and later in the code I divide them, but when I try to run it I got "operand is of incorrect type"... what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To load a floating point value into a register you need `l.s` - you really ought to spend some time reading the MIPS documentation before you go much further with his assignment.

Comment: Well, that was a VERY good point direction. Now I can `div.s $f0,$f1,$f2` but at assemble I got again "operand is of incorrect type" on $f0 when `move $a0,$f0`. I guess I can't mix Floating Point Registers and Arguments, but then, how I show the div result?

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for your MIPS system (is it SPIM ?) and see if there is a system call for displaying a floating point value.

Comment: I'm using mars and the systemcall for displaying a float value is (like in SPIM) `$v0, 2` but when I `add.s $f0,$f0,$zero` to show the result $zero becomes "operand is of incorrect type"

Comment: According to this: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html the float value to print needs to be in $f12. Also I think $zero is an integer constant so you can't use it with a floating point instruction.

Comment: Yes, I read that but even if I use $f12 instead of $f0 I can't show the result. If I `move $a0,$f12` I get NaN, if I `add.s $f12,$f12,$zero` I got operand of incorrect type because, as you said, it's an integer; if I try `add.s $f12,$f12,$f31` setting `l.s $f31, 0` I got "address out of range 0x00000000", if I reset to `l.s $f31, cero` where cero is `cero: .byte 0` I got "fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x100102b5". I really hate be so stuck, after 18 hours straight my brain is dry...

Comment: @Ashir: you probably need to do two things at this point: (1) do some reading of the MIPS and MARS documentation and (2) if anything is still not clear then post one or more new questions here on SO detailing any specific issues that you still have.

Comment: @Paul I'm clear about what I need to do: print the result of 2 / 9 division, I mean the true result (0.2222222222222222), in fact I need to print the result of ANY division that trows float as result. Thanks to you I'm in the right path but I still can't make it happend...

Comment: @Ashir: OK - read the docs carefully, understand the difference between integer and floating point instructions/data, understand the difference between immediate loads and loads from memory, and make sure you understand the syscalls. If you take care with all the details then it shouldn't be too hard to make this work. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division. Use the floating point instructions to get results in decimal. Look up the div.x instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full objectives, perhaps it suffices to use a convenient integer shortcut:  divide 2 billion by 9 and display that with an artificially inserted decimal point.  In `C`, this would be something like

```
printf ("0.%d", 2000000000 / 9);
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to divide 2 / 9, so I can't divide 2 billion by 9, besides, I need to use only registers so I can't use neither printf...

Comment: Because later I ask for 2 numbers and I need to divide them too, so there is no way for me to know what numbers are going to be divided and thus I can't divide by random billions. Beside, as I ask for 2 random numbers, there is no guarantee that I have to divide them and get for result a float number...